# Como criar um redirecionador de Url's?

Tags: php, redirecionamento-de-url

Alguém tem um sistema de redirecionamento no estilo [desse site](http://jairzinhocds.com.br/protetor.htm?url%3a=www.goo.gl/sXlYtH)?

Comment: Você poderia reformular a pergunta de maneira a dispensar o link externo para que seja entendida?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O próprio código da página pode te ajudar a resolver o problema. Lá aparecem os JS para você usar como base para sua aplicação.

**aqui é a URL do download:**

```
function download() {
url = QueryString("url")
// Remove o "http://" caso exista (apenas para não colocar duas vezes)
url = url.replace("http://", "")
// Adciona o "http://"
url = "http://" + url
top.document.location = url
}
</script>
```

**analise o código do contador**

```
<script language="JavaScript">
//<![CDATA[
var xtx=20;
function IniciaRegressivo() {
if (xtx > 0) {
document.getElementById('botao').innerHTML = '<div class="protetor-botao"><a>Aguarde '+ 
x +' segundos</a></div>';
xtx = xtx - 1;
setTimeout("IniciaRegressivo();", 1000);
} else {
document.getElementById('botao').innerHTML = '<div class="protetor-botao"><a 
ef="javascript:download();">Fazer Download</a></div>';
}    }
//]]>
</script>
```

e no  vc executa essas funções. O código está bem explicativo.

Answer (score 5):

Eu indicaria também fazer esse redirecionamento em PHP, como o exemplo abaixo:

```
<?php
$url = $_GET['url'];
if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) !== false) {
    header('Location: '.$url);
} else {
    die('Não é uma url');
}
```

É o mais indicado pois ai você pode gravar métricas de acesso, como data e hora do acesso ou mesmo IP.

Comment: Use sempre `exit;` após um redirecionamento, a não ser que você queira que o código após o `header()` seja executado. +1 para a sua resposta!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer assim:

1) Se quiser ofuscar seu link, use a função `base64_encode`

```
base64_encode('http://google.com');
```

2) se precisar passar o parâmetro para o script, por exemplo

```
http://meusite.com/redirecionar.php?l=aHR0cDovL2dvb2dsZS5jb20=
```

Pera pegar o link dentro do script. pode usar algo como:

```
$link = base64_decode($_GET['l']);
```

3) Para redirecionar, não use a função `header()` se você for exibir alguma saida antes, isso irá gerar um erro, você precisa de Javascript

```
window.location = '<?php echo $link; ?>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma simples de implementar o que busca com JavaScript poderia ser:

```htm
<html>
  <script>
    function redirect() {
      var match = /\?url=(.+)/.exec(window.location);
      if (match)
        window.location = match[1];
    }
  </script>
  <body onload="redirect();"></body>
</html>
```

Abra essa página como `www.exemplo.com/redirect.htm?url=http://www.google.com/`.

Você pode se aproveitar da mesma ideia para fazer o código de espera ou coisas similares.